# Looking for a collection of data with no clear pattern

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query to search for a collection of data with no clear pattern, in fact it conflicts with an existing pattern.

The solution I have in mind is to run the query with an AND for all the data that does have a pattern(let's assume every other record follows pattern, except for what i am looking for, so it's basically scattered with no clear way of putting it together) and them what's left over, can be retrieved and displayed.

Comment: This is way too vague for anyone on here to help you. Post some code.

Comment: Examples of the pattern?

Comment: That sounds like a good approach, can you post some sample data, and maybe form a clear question for us to answer?

Comment: Try to clarify your question and put some code you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution I have in mind is to run the query with an AND for all
>   the data that does have a pattern

Well, if you want to find everything that doesn't follow any pattern just enclose all the patterns within brackets and combine with `boolean` `AND`.

Then just put a `NOT` outside the brackets.

**Example:**

```
select * from data where
NOT (CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2 AND...AND CONDITION_N)
```

*I imagine your conditions are statements such as string comparisons using like (and wildcards) in addition to arithmetic comparisons.*

Comment: That should work i will try it.